# How to POST Json object in JQuery's load method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using jQuery's load method to invoke controller action. However the controller not able to serialize the object.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetInformation(FilterModel[] filters)
    {
       // do something
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    var data = [];
    data.push({
        field: 'field 1',
        operator: 'eq',
        value: '1'
    });

    data.push({
        field: 'field 2',
        operator: 'eq',
        value: '2'
    });       

    $('#mycontainer').load("Home/GetInformation", data, function (response)
    {
      // do something
    })
```

As per jQuery's documentation

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

So since i'm passing object, jquery is making POST request as expected however server is not able to serialize the object.

**Note**

**1>** If i change `GetInformation()` method to accept single filter(*instead of array*) like below

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult GetInformation(FilterModel filter)
   {
     // do something
   }
```

and then change JS script to send single instance of filter, then it works.

**2>** Also if I use jquery's [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method directly to POST data (*instead of using load*) by setting proper content type then it works even with array parameter.

Comment: Load up Fiddler and make sure the values being transmitted are what you expect.

Comment: Since your sending an array, you either need to stringify the data and set `contentType: 'application/json'` (easier to use the `$.ajax()` method), or you need to send name/value pairs with indexers - e.g `var data = { field[0]: 'field 1', operator[0]: 'eq', ...`

Comment: If i stringfy data then 'load' will use GET instead of POST. Also there is no option to set content type in load method

Comment: That why its better to use `ajax()` (but you can use $.ajaxSetup()` to configure the options but it is not recommended - refer the 2nd overload of the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: ajax() does work. The `load()` method is wrapper method around `ajax` with pre-configured settings. But im curious now why can't i post object with load? What im missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

I can stringify the `data` and pass to load method however, as i mentioned earlier, if `data` is not an object then load method will use GET to make the request. In my case server is expecting POST so it rejects such request.

so in order to POST array in load method, i have to pass data with parameter name `{filters:data}`. Something like below

```
 $('#mycontainer').load("Home/GetInformation", {filters: data}, function (response)
    {
      // do something
    })
```

the parameter name must match with action method's parameter name.

But to fix my issue i wrap filters array inside wrapper class. With this approach i don't have to worry about matching parameter name.

```
  public class FilterWrapper
  {
     public IEnumerable<FilterModel> Filters {get;set;}
  }
```

and update action method to accept `FilterWrapper` class instead of array.

and in javascript i pass data as single object

```
var filters = {filters : data }
$('#mycontainer').load("Home/GetInformation", filters, function (response)
    {
      // do something
    })
```

Comment: or... use one of the other ajax methods that do support what you're trying to do.